# Is an Acer C7 Chromebook worth buying as an Ubuntu netbook?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, acer, chromebook

I apologies for non technical question. I'm really low on budget, and considering buying new netbook for starting using Ubuntu, after a lame Win 8 decided to move on Linux based systems. So for the starter I want to move on Ubuntu  step by step. I choosed Acer C7 Chromebook mostly for it's price, and seem all technical characteristics are enough to run Ubuntu.

I've read a lot of reviews on Acer C7 with chrUbuntu, but still have some question. As I understand this chrUbuntu isn't an official project, and canonical doesn't support it. Also it seems that some users do have a little troubles with 12.10 version, like sound for mic and ets. So what's going to happen with 13.04? Does this Acer C7 worth buying as Ubuntu netbook? Appreciate your advices.

Comment: It might help if you get 12.10... but it's your decision...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Shopping recommendation is off topic as per our [faq] and I am going to have to close this question.

Comment: @jokerdino, sorry for mistopic, I couldn't understand was this chromebook compatible with Ubuntu or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, C7 Chromebook is not worth buying as **Ubuntu** netbook.

**First,** Chromebooks uses its own kind of BIOS replacement that is not supported by Ubuntu. So it won't boot.

**Second,** chrUbuntu is not an official version of Ubuntu and is off topic in this site.

**Third,** Ubuntu 13.04 is not out yet and as a future version of Ubuntu is off topic as well. As far as I know there is not plans for supporting Chromebook, but I may be wrong.

**Fourth,** Shopping recommendations are off topic.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the most biggest resource I've found.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer by putting the green check mark on the left if you think this is correct. This will help others.